# Angular 2 DOM Binding Data is not accurate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to compare two variables who are constantly change due to an API call.

Think a stock counter. If the stock increase I want to know this as well if it decreases.

Before the API call i store an instance of the call (object array) and then compare it to a new version of the call. This all works and as a result I can get the console to tell me if there was an increase or decrease.

I store this information right inside the array where I change a boolean to true or false depending on the result.

perfect, all is well and working. However when I bind these exact values to the DOM using a *ngFor loop as I want to cycle through all objects, they values are always false (default value). They never actually change even those console.log says they are.

Why would the DOM not bind the values correctly?

## DOM

```
<div class="ticker" *ngFor="let coinresult of coinResults; let beforecoinresult of beforeCoinResults; let aftercoinresult of afterCoinResults;">
    <div class="wrapper" *ngIf="coinresult.name != step2Selection">
        <!--<h1 *ngIf="match === false">Before: {{beforecoinresult.amount}} - After: {{aftercoinresult.amount}}</h1>-->
        <div class="pin" (click)="pinTitle(coinresult.amount, coinresult.name)">
            <i class="material-icons" *ngIf="pinnedCoinAmount != coinresult.amount">gps_not_fixed</i>
            <i class="material-icons selectedCoin" *ngIf="pinnedCoinAmount === coinresult.amount">gps_fixed</i>
        </div>

        <div class="amount" [ngClass]="{amountpinned: pinnedCoinAmount === coinresult.amount, 
                                        amountincrease: beforecoinresult.increase,
                                        amountdecrease: beforecoinresult.decrease}">
                                        {{coinresult.amount}}
        </div>
        <div class="name" [ngClass]="{  namepinned: pinnedCoinAmount === coinresult.amount, 
                                        nameincrease: beforecoinresult.increase,
                                        namedecrease: beforecoinresult.decrease}">
                                        {{coinresult.name}} 

        </div>
        {{beforecoinresult.increase}} {{beforecoinresult.decrease}}
    </div>
```

## interface

```
export interface coinResultsType{
   name: string,
   amount: number,
   increase: boolean,
   decrease: boolean
}
```

Theres a Ton of logic in my component, but I don't see value in posting it, it works and works great. So I attached an image of the console who is logging:

```
console.log(beforeCoinResults[0].increase);
console.log(beforeCoinResults[0].decrease);
```

However in the CAD ticker you can see there both false. Now, they info happens quick so you may say that it had changed to false, but rest assured I am watching but they all remain false.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `console.log` to debug your code, use `debugger` to stop the code execution and inspect the values manually. The reason is that `console.log` might not be in-sync with your code execution, and at the time the data is displayed on the console, it might have already changed. I know, it sounds confusing, specially thinking about console.log from a `sync` point of view, and not `async` point of view.

Your code might be working fine, and might be `console.log` not showing the values correctly.